# Best practices for creating large tables in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have a table with 100 million rows I'm trying to modify so it can be maintained and queried effectively.  We get about a million new rows for the table each month.
I thought I had it set up correctly with the primary index distributing rows equally and range partitions, one of which is by date, but when I tried altering the table to the current date to add a new partition, it took too long.

Now I'm not sure what else I should change.  My understanding is that each field participating in the PI and partitions should be indexed and have statistics collected for the parsing engine, even though maintaining those indexes and statistics takes time and space.

I've thought about extending the range of dates for a couple of years to avoid altering the partitions, but I've also read that Teradata doesn't recommend that practice.

So what else should I try?  Here's my create statement:

```
CREATE SET TABLE STAGE.PartD
     DATABLOCKSIZE = 1048064 BYTES
     (
      Efctv_uniq_id CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
      Cntrct_num CHAR(5) NOT NULL COMPRESS ('H2407','H2416','H2417','H2419','H2422','H2425','H2450','H2456','H2457','H2458','H2459','H2462','H5703','S0522','S4802','S5597','S5601','S5617','S5644','S5660','S5743','S5768','S5803','S5810','S5820','S5884','S5921','S5932','S5960','S5967','S7694'),
      Pbp_id SMALLINT NOT NULL COMPRESS (1 ,2 ,24 ,25 ,42 ,50 ,59 ,83 ,94 ,370 ,122 ,123 ,145 ,162 ,247 ),
      Hicn VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
      Cardhldr_id VARCHAR(20) COMPRESS '',
      Ptnt_date_of_birth DATE FORMAT 'YY/MM/DD' COMPRESS ,
      Ptnt_gender_cd CHAR(1) NOT NULL COMPRESS ('0','1','2'),
      Date_of_srvc DATE FORMAT 'YY/MM/DD' NOT NULL,
      Paid_dt DATE FORMAT 'YY/MM/DD' COMPRESS ,
      Product_srvc_id VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL COMPRESS ('~','62175011843','00088222033'),
      Srvc_prvdr_id_qlfyr CHAR(2) NOT NULL COMPRESS ('01','07','99'),
      Srvc_prvdr_id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
      Fill_num BYTEINT NOT NULL COMPRESS (0 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10 ,11 ,12 ,13 ,14 ),
      Dspnsng_stus CHAR(1) NOT NULL COMPRESS ' ',
      Cmpnd_cd CHAR(1) COMPRESS '1',
      Daw_prod_slctn_cd CHAR(1) COMPRESS '0',
      Qty_dspnsd CHAR(10) NOT NULL COMPRESS ('0000004000','0000010000','0000014000','0000015000','0000020000','0000028000','0000030000','0000031000','0000045000','0000056000','0000060000','0000090000','0000100000','0000120000','0000180000'),
      Days_suply SMALLINT COMPRESS (0 ,3 ,5 ,7 ,10 ,14 ,15 ,20 ,25 ,28 ,30 ,31 ,34 ,90 ),
      Prscrb_id_qlfyr CHAR(2) COMPRESS ('  ','01','12'),
      Prscrb_id VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL COMPRESS '',
      Drug_cvrg_stus_cd CHAR(1) COMPRESS (' ','C','E','O'),
      Adjsmt_del_cd CHAR(1) COMPRESS (' ','A','D'),
      Non_stand_frmt_cd CHAR(1) COMPRESS (' ','B','C','X'),
      Prcng_excptn_cd CHAR(1) COMPRESS (' ','M','O'),
      Uniq_id CHAR(13) NOT NULL,
      FinalVersionInd CHAR(1),
      LoadID SMALLINT NOT NULL)
PRIMARY INDEX pi ( Efctv_uniq_id ,LoadID )
PARTITION BY ( RANGE_N(LoadID  BETWEEN 1  AND 10000  EACH 1 ),
                            RANGE_N(Date_of_srvc  BETWEEN DATE '2007-01-01' AND ADD_MONTHS((DATE ),(-1 )) EACH INTERVAL '1' MONTH ) )
UNIQUE INDEX ui ( Efctv_uniq_id ,LoadID )
INDEX Efctv_uniq_id ( Efctv_uniq_id )
INDEX Date_of_srvc ( Date_of_srvc )
INDEX LoadID ( LoadID );
```

I need the UI in the staging environment so it doesn't allow the same data to get loaded more than once.  I've taken that index out of the table in the prod environment.

avgCurrentPerm is 722027691, maxPeakPerm is 730772992, and skewFactor is 0.094412.

Thanks for any help.

---

changed it to:

```
PRIMARY INDEX pi ( Efctv_uniq_id ,LoadID )
PARTITION BY ( 
RANGE_N(LoadID  BETWEEN 644  AND 10000  EACH 1 ),
RANGE_N(Date_of_srvc  BETWEEN DATE '2007-01-01' AND DATE '2030-01-01' 
EACH INTERVAL '1' MONTH ) );
```

seeing:
avgCurrentPerm 377035904    maxPeakPerm 377372160   skewFactor 0.089105

and collecting these stats:

```
COLLECT STATS 
COLUMN (PARTITION), 
COLUMN (loadid), 
COLUMN (Efctv_uniq_id), 
COLUMN (Date_of_srvc) 
ON STAGE.PartD;
```

---

and I'm getting the impression that creating unique indexes and partition ranges using the current date is a bad idea?

Comment: not sure about the downvote, if there's additional information needed, I can supply it.  I'm looking for general recommendations beyond what I've already found for optimizing large tables in Teradata.

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding is that each field participating in the PI and
>   partitions should be indexed

Nope, additional indexes on the partitioning/PI columns are useless.

And if you switch to MERGE instead of INSERT/UPDATE you don't need the USI, too.

Finally better define `Date_of_srvc` until 2030 to avoid ADD RANGE (where did you get the recommendation to run Alter Table?)

Comment: I've seen the `Alter Table` recommendation ( `ALTER TABLE STAGE.PartD TO CURRENT`, usually `with insert` or `delete`) in several places but I'm not finding any great references right now.  I can remove the additional indexes and statistics, though, I thought I only got to skip statistics for a UPI set of fields.  I can also try the `MERGE`, but it won't be merging any rows, they'll all be inserted.  Are you saying if I accidentally reload data, the `MERGE` will overwrite the rows instead of failing?

Comment: oh, wait, do I not need the indexes, but still need to collect stats on partition/PI fields?

Comment: @Beth: Stats are still needed. `MERGE` should be based on the logical Primary Key of the target table and thus an existing row will be updated (or ignored).